# Sending actions through Responder Chain in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, selector

I'm trying to send actions through the Responder Chain in Swift.

Consider :

```swift
final class AppDelegate: NSObject {
    @IBAction private func subscribe(_ sender: Any?) { /* ... */ }
}

NSApp.sendAction(#selector(subscribe(_:)),
                           to: nil,
                           from: nil)
```

Swift complains the function `subscribe(_:)` is inaccessible due to private protection level.
If I make the function internal, Swift complains I use an undefined identifier (given I don't prepend the class name to the function name).

Prepending the class name to the selector works, but I'm trying to avoid :

- making the function internal (though I'm unconfident about this, private is private)
- prepending the class name to the selector.

Any idea about how to do this ?

Comment: "If I make the function internal, Swift complains I use an undefined identifier." really? That should work, from what I can tell

Comment: @Alexander Really yes, I'm trying to send the action from outside the definition of the class receiving the action

Comment: That would be an issue for `private` access, but it should be fine for `internal`, which would make the function available to the whole module (app target, framework, whatever it may be). Are you trying to send this action from a different module

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably didn't describe it correctly. I get inaccessible function error when it's private. If I turn it internal, _without prepending the class name_, I get the undefined identifier error. I edited the question to make this clear